# How to get original image using PHImageManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, phasset, phimagemanager

I am using below code to get original image from PHAsset:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;
requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:phasset
                                                                   targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                                                                  contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                                                                      options:requestOptions
                                                                resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                                    if (image) {
                                                                                                        }
}];
```

But found that, image size is greater than the original size. I picked `54 MB` file but found its size `123.5MB` in response.
Using below code to calculate image size:

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSLog(@"img size: %@", [[NSByteCountFormatter new] stringFromByteCount:imgData.length]);
```

Any idea how to get an original image using  `[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:` API.

Comment: I have a question: how do you know the original size?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to share my code in Swift 5.
In my case, the following code works well on iOS 14.5.1.

```
extension PHAsset {
    func getImageData(_ index: Int, completionHandler: @escaping((_ index: Int, _ image: UIImage?)->Void)) {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = true
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: self, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in
            completionHandler(index, image)
        })
    }
}
```

Because I call getImageData in background thread and the return value is not correctly ordered, I use a variable named index for calling order and in turn, pass it to completionHanlder so that I can know from where the return value is.
If you don't need index variable, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to get original image below, it worked for me. Hope it works for you, too.

```
    func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    option.resizeMode = .none
    
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option) { (result, info) in
        thumbnail = result!
    }
    return thumbnail
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use following code to get original image. I have code in `Swift`, you should convert it to `Objective-C`

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: phAssets.firstObject!, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: requestOption) { (image, dictResult) in

    // Get file path url of original image.
    if let url = dictResult!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? URL {
        self.getImageFromFileUrl(url)
    }
}


func getImageFromFileUrl(_ fileUrl: URL) {

    // Get dat from url, here I have not using catch block, you must use it for swift.
    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)

    // Get image from data
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

    // Size count, which is same as original image
    let size = ByteCountFormatter()
    print("image size = \(size.string(fromByteCount: Int64(imageData!.count)))")
}
```

For details, I have added comment above the line of code.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar. Let check.

Comment: @iKT, Have you checked ?